# Rotating a right triangle

Tags: geometry

When a right triangle is **rotated about one leg**, the volume of the generated solid is **800π cu. cm.** When the triangle is **rotated about the other leg**, the volume of the generated solid is **1920π cu. cm.** What is the length in cm of the hypotenuse of the triangle?

What I know is that it will form cones when rotated. I am unsure on what step to take next however.

Comment: The volume of the cone is $\pi r^2h/3$ where $r$ is the radius of the base and $h$ is the height. In your case $r$ and $h$ will be each 'leg' of the triangle $x,y$. So, you have that $\pi x^2y/3=800$ and $\pi y^2x/3=1920$. You could solve this system to obtain $x$ and $y$. Once you have them the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, by Pythagoras.

Comment: To solve the system of equations you could divide the two equations to get $x/y=800/1920$. Solve for $y$ to get $y=1920x/800$. Then put this in one of the equations, say the first, $\pi x^2(1920x/800)/3=800$ and solve for $x$ here to get $x=10/\sqrt[3]{\pi}$. Putting this in the equation for $y$ gives $y=24/\sqrt[3]{\pi}$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod It's just $10$ and $24$ because the volume isn't $800$ but $800\pi$ instead.